# Envoy setup for Joomla

Tags: git

For the last few months, I have been working with Laravel, and I am just impressed the way the site get deployed to the server.

Is there any way to deploy Joomla site using Envoy task runner like Laravel, so there is no need of login to server and pull from bitbucket?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to answer my own question. bcoz it may help others.

Laravel implemented it with the help of `Envoy`,

The requirement can be fixed in few ways.

1. Write a bash script for doing deployment.
2. Use the [Git hooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) options.
3. Use [Bit Bucket Hooks](http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2013/11/19/automated-git-deployments-from-bitbucket/) options.

Here I will explain bash script that is what I preferred.

```
#!/bin/bash
## Project Deployment Script ##
ssh username@hostname <<'ENDSSH'
cd /home/phpadmin/Development/Project ;
git pull origin master;
ENDSSH
```

save the above file as `deploy.sh` then make sure it had execute permission. then simply run it from CLI.
now you will get password prompt for server user, just enter it and done !.

Hope it helps someone ..

Answer (score 2):

In Joomla, there is no similar own tool for defining common tasks to be run on your remote servers. As usual, you can integrate Jenkins, Docker, Gulp, Bower or other tools to automate tasks.

Related with the question, I have found these JAB sessions are interesting:

- [Setting up Jenkins with Docker to Test your Joomla! Extension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrXkoyzQwi4&list=PLSwFVRVZ3joRlHSiJ8JxKsvI9uWlr1tik&index=14)
- [Gulp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ihi0KDr-Bs&index=45&list=PLSwFVRVZ3joRlHSiJ8JxKsvI9uWlr1tik)